# Python список файлов FTP

Tags: python, ftp

Пример из мануала:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP()
ftp.login()
data = ftp.retrlines('LIST')
print(data)
```

Но переменная data вместо списка файлов содержит сообщение: '226 Transfer complete.'
Как присвоить переменной список имеющихся файлов?

Comment: А каталог не пустой, случаем?

Comment: Каталог не пустой. Список содержимого выводится на экран, но не присваивается переменной.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде работает.

Используя [FTP.nlst](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.nlst):

```
list_files = ftp.nlst()
print(list_files)
```

Comment: Кст, попробуйте еще `mlsd()`

Comment: К сожалению содержание переменной: <generator object mlsd at 0x7f664dd08fc0>

Comment: Вы с питоном не работали ранее? Вам вернули генератор, обработайте его, например `list_files = list(ftp.mlsd())`

Comment: Не могу назвать себя специалистом в питоне.)))  Благодарю!